# Extract records by amount summary from second table

Tags: mysql

My query:

```
SELECT fd.*
FROM `fin_document` as fd
LEFT JOIN `fin_income` as fi ON fd.id=fi.document_id
WHERE fd.dt_payment < NOW()
HAVING SUM(fi.amount) < fd.total_amount
```

which is obviously not correct, has to retrieve all records from `fin_document` where `dt_payment` is earlier than `NOW()`. This part is ok. But I have to filter them by the payments made on this documents. One document can have more than 1 payment ( 2,3,4,5 ...). In `fin_income` are those payments. There is column `document_id` in `fin_income` table which is foreign key `fin_income.document_id=fin_document.id`. The problem ( at least for me ) is that I don't have a specific `id` criterion and the amount is made from all records from `fin_income` table. I also have to find records that still don't have payments on them ( they don't have rows in `fin_income` ).

```
fin_document:
+-------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)                   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dt_payment        | date                      | YES  |     | NULL    |                
| total_amount      | decimal(10,2)             | NO   |     | 0.00    |                       
+-------------------+---------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

fin_income:
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| document_id      | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| amount           | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | 0.00              |                
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You could simplify this question by chopping the tables to include only the fields necessary to illustrate your problem. You could also add sample data and expected output as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can try this:

```
SELECT fd.*, SUM(IFNULL(fi.amount, 0)) as sum_amount, COUNT(fi.amount) as count_amount
FROM `fin_document` as fd
LEFT JOIN `fin_income` as fi ON fd.id=fi.document_id
WHERE fd.dt_payment < NOW()

GROUP BY fd.id

HAVING sum_amount < fd.total_amount # condition for searching by sum of payments

AND count_amount = {needed_count}   # condition for searching by count of payments;
                                    # documents without payments will have
                                    # sum and count equal to 0
```

All aggregations are made in `SELECT` part, then all documents are grouped by id to avoid duplicates in result and make possible to use aggregation results (SUM, COUNT). And finally you can apply needed conditions (about date, paid sum or count of payments).

*Note*: pay attention that `GROUP BY` significantly increases execution time for a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

You may just need a correlated sub query to test income

```
drop table if exists fin_document,fin_income;
create table fin_document
(id                 int(11),                 
dt_payment         date    ,                          
total_amount       decimal(10,2)
)   ;        


create table fin_income
( id                int(11)       ,
 document_id       int(11)       ,
 amount            decimal(10,2) 
);

insert into fin_document values
(1,'2019-05-31',1000),
(2,'2019-06-10',1000),
(3,'2019-07-10',1000);

insert into fin_income values
(1,1,5),(1,1,5);

SELECT fd.*,(select coalesce(sum(fi.amount),0) from fin_income fi where fd.id=fi.document_id) income
FROM `fin_document` as fd
WHERE fd.dt_payment < NOW() and
fd.total_amount > (select coalesce(sum(fi.amount),0) from fin_income fi where fd.id=fi.document_id);

+------+------------+--------------+--------+
| id   | dt_payment | total_amount | income |
+------+------------+--------------+--------+
|    1 | 2019-05-31 |      1000.00 |  10.00 |
|    2 | 2019-06-10 |      1000.00 |   0.00 |
+------+------------+--------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```